# Why does llvm-config disables exceptions for me?

Tags: llvm, llvm-c++-api, llvm-config

I was compiling a code using LLVM and it failed compiling:

```
In file included from main.cpp:8:
In file included from /usr/lib/llvm-12/include/llvm/IR/LLVMContext.h:19:
In file included from /usr/lib/llvm-12/include/llvm/Support/CBindingWrapping.h:17:
/usr/lib/llvm-12/include/llvm/Support/Casting.h:309:7: error: cannot use 'throw' with exceptions disabled
      throw runtime_error("Address sanitizer is not turned on.");
      ^
```

I realized my `llvm-config` is disabling the exceptions for me.

```
llvm-config-12 --cxxflags --ldflags --system-libs --libs core
```

Returns

```
-I/usr/lib/llvm-12/include -std=c++14   -fno-exceptions -D_GNU_SOURCE -D__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS -D__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS -D__STDC_LIMIT_MACROS
-L/usr/lib/llvm-12/lib 
-lLLVM-12
```

In the past, I was not observing `-fno-exceptions` at all. A typical example should look like [this](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/ruby-llvm/LLVM/CONFIG).

Where does this exception prevention come from?

Comment: From the [coding standards](https://llvm.org/docs/CodingStandards.html#do-not-use-rtti-or-exceptions).

Comment: @arnt, this exception and the others are inside llvm library code. I cannot remove them.

Comment: I suppose I was too quick; I thought you just wanted to know where the prevention comes from.